# ERROR ITMS-9000: Invalid segment Alignment

Tags: ios, flash

I am using windows 8.0, adobe flash professional CC and AIR SDK 14 to develop my app.

I am submitting my ipa file to appstore through application loader.

I got an error message

ERROR ITMS-9000:"Inavalid segment alignment. this app does not have proper segment alignment and should be rebuilt with the latest version of Xcode Please contact Developer Technical Support if you need further assistence."

There is a solution for mac users https://forums.adobe.com/message/6763023#6763023 But how to solve this issue on windows PC.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, Flash CC 2014, AIR SDK 15, Windows 7. We don't have XCode at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Flash Builder 4.7 (32 Bit) PC Users:

Use Apache FlexSDK 14 with Flash 14 and Air 14 in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\sdks` to avoid `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7` error when you compile the ipa with Flash Builder. (see [this](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html))

Use newest AirSDK 16 Beta in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK`. (See [this](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html))

Replace `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\sdks\4.13.0\lib\aot\bin` folder with the folder in the AIR 16 Beta SDK `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\lib\aot\bin` to avoid `invalid segment alignement` error if you upload the ipa with the application uploader to the App Store.